# Error request for member 'find'

Tags: c++, string

```
string input;
string code[4];

if (code.find(o) == input.find(o))
{

}
```

For this line it gives me the error: `request for member 'find' in 'code', which is of non-class type 'std::string [4]'`

Both string `input` and string `code` have `string` values in them.

Comment: Is this a repost?  I could swear this is a smaller snippet from a question from earlier today.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that `code` is an array of strings, so you need something like

```
code[someIndex].find(o) == ....
```

Comment: alright so i tried        if (code[o].find(o) == input[o].find(o)) {

    } and it says error: request of member 'find' in 'input.std::basic_string<_ChatT,_Traits,_Allec>::operator[] ? whats that even mean

Comment: @user2809361 because `input` is not an array? It is your code, please read it crefully.

Answer (score 0):

The error says all , `code` is an array of `std::string`

compare using

`code[i].find(o)`

`i` = looping index

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error:

> error: request for member 'find' in 'code', which is of non-class type 'std::string [4]

It is telling you that:

- `code` is of type `std::string [4]` (which is an array of 4 `std::string` objects)
- it couldn't find the member function `find` you are requesting

Just select the correct index for the string you want to call `find` on or do a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    if (code[i].find(o) == input.find(o))
        // ...
```

Note that, if you can, you should try to avoid C-style arrays and use `std::array` (since C++11) or `std::vector` instead.